# How can you have multiple things happen during onscreenclick for python? (turtle)

Tags: python, python-turtle

I'm trying as a personal project to create a game in python using turtle, but I've run into an issue

```
def player_headto(x, y):
    player.left(player.towards(x, y) - player.heading())
    player.goto(x, y)
  window.onscreenclick(player_headto)
  def currency(x, y):
    c_amount = 0
    if x >= 100 and x <= 150:
      if y >= 50 and y <= 100:
        c_amount = c_amount + 1
        print(str(c_amount))
      else:
        print(str(c_amount))
    else:
      print(str(c_amount))
  window.onscreenclick(currency)
```

I'm not able to have multiple things happen all at once each click. I've tried a bunch, but it always either returns an error or only does one.

Comment: Try defining a single method handle_click() that does everything you want to happen when a click happens. Instead of binding multiple different methods to onscreenclick

Answer (score 1):

> I'm not able to have multiple things happen all at once each click.

You don't need threading or nor a single click hander that does everything.  What you need is the poorly documented `add` argument to `onscreenclick()` aka `screen.onclick()`.  Here's a simple example:

```
from turtle import Screen, Turtle

def draw_circle(x, y):
    turtle.circle(100)

def change_background(x, y):
    screen.bgcolor('red')

turtle = Turtle()

screen = Screen()

screen.onclick(change_background)
screen.onclick(draw_circle, add=True)

screen.mainloop()
```

Of course, both won't happen *all at once* but rather sequentially.  Which is what you'd get with a single click hander that does everything, or even threading, as all turtle graphic operations have to handled by the main thread.

Answer (score 0):

use multi threading, which makes the processes multi task